How modify a serialVersionUID at runtime
I'm using a third party library to connect to an external system, everything was working fine but suddenly i'm having serialization errors
java.io.InvalidClassException: com.essbase.api.base.EssException; local class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID = 9031463779199124957, local class serialVersionUID = -3889253203225845868

i'm pretty sure that my library is still compatible with the external system so i tried to use javassist to modify the serialVersionUID of my local com.essbase.api.base.EssException
CtClass cc = pool.get("com.essbase.api.base.EssException");
cc.defrost();
CtField serialField=new CtField(CtClass.longType, "serialVersionUID",cc);
serialField.setModifiers(Modifier.PRIVATE);
serialField.setModifiers(Modifier.STATIC);
serialField.setModifiers(Modifier.FINAL);        
cc.addField(serialField, CtField.Initializer.constant(9031463779199124957l));

The error persists but it says that my local serialVersionUID is now -7214799155395914399 so this is doing something.
Have ay ideas of how to turn my serialVersionUID to 9031463779199124957l  ?

Why not change serialVersionUID directly in your code ?

How can i do that? the conflicting serialVersionUID  it's from a third party library wich i don't have the source code

Sorry, I thought it was your own code. Then can you find a correct jar consistent with the server side, because there may be imcompatible changes in EssException for a different serialVersionUID.

Another way that i dont recommend yet. Write your own EssException with same package, shadowing the one from third-party jar.

There is a reason the serialVersionUID has changed, and it most likely means your local client jars are NOT compatible with the version used at the remote side. So you should rather update your client libs.

@GyroGearless i would do it if i had those jars. In the meantime i'm searching for a workaround, so i would appreciate an answer to my question

A "workaround" like the one you've found is just likely to be broken less obviously than the current state.  It will still be broken.  There is not likely to be any correct workaround other than what @GyroGearless has described.

I finally make it work, changing the modifiers of the injected Field to this:
serialField.setModifiers(Modifier.STATIC | Modifier.FINAL);

so this is the working code, and the comunication with the server is now restored:
ClassPool pool = ClassPool.getDefault();
pool.insertClassPath(new ClassClassPath(MainTest.class));
CtClass cc = pool.get("com.essbase.api.base.EssException");
cc.defrost();
CtField serialField=new CtField(CtClass.longType, "serialVersionUID",cc);
serialField.setModifiers(Modifier.STATIC | Modifier.FINAL);
cc.addField(serialField, CtField.Initializer.constant(9031463779199124957l));
Class clazz=cc.toClass();

